# Material animations not working with property?

Tags: animation, game-engine, materials

I've used material animations and they work fine, even with properties. For some odd reason, the following construction doesn't work:[image]

"hit_frame" works just fine. I don't know why, but the material animation *does not* follow it. It seems that it keeps displaying frame 1 instead of 0-10 even though the property is 0-10. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why, but material animations only work when in multitexture. so far as I can see this is the only reason to choose multi over GLSL. This is screwy, and I hope BGE team gets it fixed quick because I don't know any work arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the action actuator after changing the property. The above image shows you activate it only when setting the property to zero.

I suggest you connect the fourth controller with the action actuator too.